# How to bulk save images from URLs

Tags: download

I have 1,200 URLs that point to images. I'd like to save them all to my hard drive. How can I accomplish this with one bulk operation?

Comment: Are the urls of the images themselves or of pages with images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [HTTrack](http://httrack.com) for a graphical interface option. If you don't mind using the command line, [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) can accept a text file as input (with the `-i` switch) containing a list of URLs to download.

Comment: I just tested the software, I really like what it does, do you know how to keep the original filename? The filename is in the link for example 1250757780.jpg and it's from this link  img/i.php?type=i&file=1250757780.jpg

Comment: In **Preferences and mirror options** go to the **build** tab. Check off the box **hide query strings**. That should do the trick. You could also set your own custom save format on the built tab after clicking **options**.

Comment: Indeed, the problem is that it saves names like: i76f3.jpg it should be something like :1250757780.jpg

Comment: I found good software, it's PicaLoader, this one has a option to save the image with a complete url name

Comment: Oh, do you want me to add it to my answer?

Comment: Sorry for the delay :)

Comment: For the record, CocoaWget for Mac provides a graphical interface for some basic wget commands.  The current version (2.7) allows you to paste in a list of URLS to the single URL field and it will add each of them to the download queue.

Answer (score 0):

In Unix or cygwin, you can use wget to get the contents of a url.  I believe something as simple as `cat list_of_urls.txt | wget` would probably do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

[Curl](http://curl.haxx.se/), [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/), [fetch](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/FreeBSD/fetch.1.html), [snarf](http://www.xach.com/snarf/), [lynx](http://lynx.isc.org/) for Unix / Linux and ported to [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [Mingw](http://www.mingw.org/) for Windows.